# Extend PHP Class only if other class is defined

Tags: php, class, oop, extend

Some may argue that this could be bad practice due to potential inconsistencies, however, I am wondering how (if possible) I could tell a class to extend another class, but only if it's defined.

I'm aware this doesn't work, but what I'm effectively after is:

```
class MyClass extends (class_exists('OtherClass') ? OtherClass : null)
```

Or maybe a function that would run in the `constructor` to set up the extend if the class exists.

I of course want to avoid..

```
if(class_exists('OtherClass'))
{
    class MyClass extends OtherClass
    {
        //The class
    }
}
else
{
    class MyClass
    {
        //The class
    }
}
```

.. because of the massive duplication of code.

I've looked for answers on Google and around the site, but found nothing - if I have duplicated a question however, do let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could create a middle-man class that's created inside the `class_exists()` condition, but without its own behavior:

```
if (class_exists('OtherClass')) {
    class MiddleManClass extends OtherClass { }
} else {
    class MiddleManClass { }
}

class MyClass extends MiddleManClass {
    // The class code here
}
```

This makes the class hierarchy include one more class, but has no duplicated code (has no code actually) and methods inside `MyClass` can reach the `OtherClass` with `parent::` or `$this` as usual if it was available.

Comment: Yes of course! I was pseudo-coding something like this in my head, but couldn't fabricate anything useful. Cheers.

Comment: Yesterday I saw the same code In the legacy code of one project in which I am working. 

Then I am wordering how Is the better way to do that operation. 

I think that there are several solutions respecting the standard of PHP. 

Also, I am not able to see the problems that this solutions could causes, for example: autoload, apc, etc. 

Thanks.